# How to get an Index of a specific DataRow by its Column-Value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datatable

By trying to avoid to many foreach()->if() routines, i tried a lambda-concept to search through a bunch of DataTables. I had no errors until i debugged my code to see it does not work, because its not allowed to ask my datarow-column for its index... is there any way to make this work instead of using IndexOf()?

```
    static Entity.Produkt ProduktConstructor(DataRow dr)
    {
        Entity.Produkt p = new Entity.Produkt();
        DataTable dt = Entity.KbMirror.mirror.Tables["Produkt"];

        p.id = Guid.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
        p.name = dr[1].ToString();
        byte[] ba = dt.Rows[dt.IndexOf(dt.Select().Where(r => r[0].ToString() == p.id.ToString()))]["ProduktLogo"];
        p.logo = Converter.ImageConverter.BA2Image(ba);
        foreach (DataRow pvdr in Entity.KbMirror.mirror.Tables["Produkt_Version"].Rows)
            if (Guid.Parse(pvdr[1].ToString()) == p.id)
                p.version.Add(VersionConstructor(Guid.Parse(pvdr[2].ToString() ), Guid.Parse(pvdr[0].ToString() ) ) );
        return p;
    }
    static Entity.Version VersionConstructor(Guid vid, Guid pvid)
    {
        Entity.Version version = new Entity.Version();
        DataTable dt = Entity.KbMirror.mirror.Tables["Version"];

        version.id = vid;
        version.name = dt.Rows[dt.IndexOf(dt.Select().Where(r =>r[0].ToString() == vid.ToString()))][1].ToString();
        foreach (DataRow cvdr in Entity.KbMirror.mirror.Tables["Customer_ProduktVersion"].Rows)
            if (Guid.Parse(cvdr[2].ToString()) == pvid)
                version.customerCollection.Add(CustomerConstructor(Guid.Parse(cvdr[1].ToString())));
        return version;
    }
```

EDIT:

error occures when I use "IndexOf()" like this:

```
        byte[] ba = dt.Rows[dt.IndexOf(dt.Select().Where(r => r[0].ToString() == p.id.ToString()))]["ProduktLogo"];
```

Comment: I suggest to use 'LINQ to DataSet'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the entire table as opposed to just the row? Once you pass the entire table, then you can reference just that row of the table.

Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
     // Fill the DataSet.
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     FillDataSet(ds);

     DataTable products = ds.Tables["Product"];

     IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
         from product in products.AsEnumerable()
         select product;

     Console.WriteLine("Product Names:");
     foreach (DataRow p in query)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(p.Field<string>("Name"));
     }
```

Comment: this is not realy what i'm looking for. actualy i simply want to query a datatable for the index of a row by any value in a special column.